# Getting garbled response when invoking Java API deployed on Windows server using jodd.http, despite specifying UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, http, character-encoding, windows-server

I'm encountering an issue when remotely invoking a Java API deployed on a Windows server. While I can successfully make the call using Apipost(A software similar to Postman) and receive data encoded in UTF-8 without any garbled characters, I face a problem when invoking it using the following code snippet:

```java
public static String post(String url, String jsonStr) {
    HttpResponse resp = HttpRequest.post(url)
            .connectionTimeout(60000)
            .timeout(60000)
            .contentType("application/json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
            .bodyText(jsonStr, "application/json", "utf-8")
            .charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
            .send();
    resp.charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    return resp.bodyText();
}
```

I'm using jodd.http for this purpose, and here's the Maven dependency:

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
    <artifactId>jodd-http</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The following image is a screenshot of me calling the API using Apipost(A software similar to Postman).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCMM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCMfF.png)
The following is a screenshot of the log for my service invocation interface.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZ1T.png)
Despite specifying UTF-8 encoding, I receive garbled text in the response. What could be causing this issue?

I expected that by specifying UTF-8 encoding and ensuring proper encoding on the server side, the response would display correctly without any garbled characters. However, despite these efforts, I continued to receive garbled text in the response.I'm hoping to receive assistance from experts in resolving this issue. (￣▽￣)~*

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Have you tested that your logger can actually render the UTF-8 code points which are in your response?